# editText box not working properly. Android

Tags: android, android-edittext

I'm trying to get values out of edittext boxes and on the click of a button, I want to compare if the text inside the edittext box matches a certain value. If it does, a new intent should be called. If it doesn't it should show an error. Here is my code after the button is clicked...

```
     if(v.getId() == R.id.button1){

        id = et1.getText().toString();
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "Value of id is: " + id, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();

        if(id == "abc"){
            Intent i= new Intent(Slogin.this, Sales.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }else{
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "Wrong id pass",                                                                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.show();
        }
```

Now the problem is that even when I enter "abc" (without the double commas), it still shows me the error "Wrong id pass". While the Toast clearly shows that I have entered abd and the string id now holds the value "abc". Help required...

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
if(id.equals("abc"))
```

instead Of

```
 if(id == "abc")
```